# libhal1 needs to be reinstalledbut cant find an index for it

Tags: system, archive

I cant run any programs without this "libhal1" package or something and i cant figure out how to install it. someone please help. Greatly appreciated

Comment: ^^ Second answer (`apt-file`)

Comment: Could you give me the command for terminal to install it?

Comment: I don't know which package contains `libhal1`, but you can use the second answer in the question I linked to find out.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a`

Answer (score 0):

**If** you have Ubuntu **12.04** installed:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libhal1
```